# Creating a Master/Detail app in Plunker with Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Building on from some good standard Ionic 2 plunkers here http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsoPeE?p=preview and 
http://plnkr.co/edit/WBeRRJyYucLwvckjh5W7?p=preview

Can you help tweak my Master/Detail Plunker? I thought I had all the parts in place but missing something as it produces a white screen.

**Here is my attempt at a Master/Detail plunk
http://plnkr.co/edit/7NHIYMA3TUdd5nOkoXyF?p=preview**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { MasterPage } from '../pages/master/master';
import { DetailPage } from '../pages/detail/detail';

import { Sheetsu } from '../providers/sheetsu';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(AppComponent) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomePage, MasterPage, DetailPage],
  entryComponents: [ HomePage, MasterPage, DetailPage ],
  bootstrap: [ IonicApp ],
  providers: [ Sheetsu ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5V36C9QHYDGBIqSIfBUl?p=preview

You had several mistakes

1) `import { Sheetsu } from '../providers/sheetsu';` <- your file is called `Sheetsu`, with a capital S

2) Your relative paths are wrong, you've made it complicated for yourself by putting `pages: 'pages',` inside your config, and for example:

`import { MasterPage } from '../pages/master/master';`

inside `HomePage` should be

`import { MasterPage } from '../master/master';`

3) You are using `"module": "commonjs",` but not taking advantage of relative html urls:

```
templateUrl: 'pages/master/master.html', -> `templateUrl: './master.html',`
```

with `moduleId: module.id` inside your `@Component`

4) Your button click `return this.http.get('../assets/sheetsu.json')` should be `return this.http.get('./assets/sheetsu.json')`